# Executing a script in windows and locking down a script

Tags: python, windows, security

I have two brief question:

1. Is there a way that I can click on my script and get the cmd prompt to start (I'm using Python cmd; a command line in dos)?
2. Can I lock down my script so no one can look at it, or at least change anything?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you saying you want a cmd.exe prompt? If so, Why not `Start...Run...cmd.exe`?

Comment: If you're using Python, why have you not tagged your question thusly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are shipping your code to third parties. If you don't want them to look at your code you can create a [frozen binary](http://www.py2exe.org/). This creates a .exe that can't be just opened with notepad and edited.

Note that this isn't a very secure way, they can still extract the code out of it, if they are skilled.